# Vaadin flow: byte[] to image

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I try to display an image, stored as blob in a table.

So I need to convert a byte[] into a Vaadin Image class (I guess that's the best way to display it ?).

I try this solution (4 years old):

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/10271496/byte-array-to-vaadin-image

it's not working :

```
new StreamResource.StreamSource() { -> Cannot resolve symbol 'StreamSource'
```

How can I do it in Vaadin 13 ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution:

```
private Image convertToImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource("isr", new InputStreamFactory() {
        @Override
        public InputStream createInputStream() {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        }
    });
    return new Image(streamResource, "photo");
}
```